# Acrescentar ordem dos registros de acordo a data e id

Tags: r, dplyr

No R, eu tenho os seguintes dados:

```
 id      date        
2380    10/30/12    
2380    10/31/12    
2380    11/1/12     
2380    11/2/12     
20103   10/30/12   
20103   12/31/12
```

E eu quero acrescentar uma coluna com a ordem dos registros de acordo com a data e o id, por exemplo:

```
id      date       ordem 
2380    10/30/12    1
2380    10/31/12    2
2380    11/1/12     3
2380    11/2/12     4
20103   10/30/12    1
20103   12/31/12    2
20100   10/05/12    2
20100   05/04/12    1
20100   11/1/12     3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em R base, pode fazer o que a pergunta pede com a função `ave`. É preciso notar que a saída de `ave` é da mesma classe que o primeiro argumento, portanto deve-se passar a coluna `date` como um vetor numérico.

```
dados$date <- as.Date(dados$date, "%m/%d/%y")
dados$ordem2 <- ave(as.numeric(dados$date), dados$id, FUN = order)

dados
#     id       date ordem ordem2
#1  2380 2012-10-30     1      1
#2  2380 2012-10-31     2      2
#3  2380 2012-11-01     3      3
#4  2380 2012-11-02     4      4
#5 20103 2012-10-30     1      1
#6 20103 2012-12-31     2      2
#7 20100 2012-10-05     2      2
#8 20100 2012-05-04     1      1
#9 20100 2012-11-01     3      3
```

**Dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
id      date       ordem 
2380    10/30/12    1
2380    10/31/12    2
2380    11/1/12     3
2380    11/2/12     4
20103   10/30/12    1
20103   12/31/12    2
20100   10/05/12    2
20100   05/04/12    1
20100   11/1/12     3
", header = TRUE)
```